# Broken network configuration after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, 22.04

## Problem

Almost all networking fails. Domain names will not resolve, websites won't load, and even most `ping` commands on a local network will fail. For example:

- `ping localhost` results in 100% packet loss and will always time out if a threshold is set.
- `ping 8.8.8.8` results in 100% packet loss and will always time out if a threshold is set.
- `ping ::1` (localhost on IPv6) works.
- `ping 2001:4860:4860::8888` (Google DNS on IPv6) results in `ping: connect: Network is unreachable`.

The outputs of `ip addr` indicate that my ethernet adapter is not found among the devices listed, and `lshw` also shows it as missing.

I assume from this that there are some remaining uninstalled drivers or that the upgrade did not successfully upgrade the device drivers, in addition to potential other networking issues generated by this upgrade process. So there may be more than one problem here; the `ping` issue is the most fundamental, as it prevents me from reinstalling packages that might fix additional issues.

I have attempted some fixes to manually restore networking capabilities, such as adding an entry for my wifi device in `/etc/network/interfaces` and also again in `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`. These were not successful. I don't know enough to try more fixes, which is why I am asking here.

## Additional Context

### `systemctl status networking`

There may be potential issues with `resolved`.

```
$ systemctl status networking
    ifup[1634]: /etc/network/if-up.d/resolved: 12: mystatedir: not found
```

### `systemd-resolved`

The systemd / systemctl logs indicate a degraded state for `systemd-resolved` - it loops back and forth between two degraded states as indicated by the logs.

```
$ systemctl status systemd-resolved:
    Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 192.168.1.1
    Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 192.168.1.1
    ...
```

I have saved the output of the [`wireless-info` shell script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) which has command outputs with details redacted; it is available as a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/afoltzm/1426aea427f8ae28ae0f07dc3fb3d9b8) for maximal information.

Comment: Check your Date settings. If it's too far off you may find Internet won't work.

Comment: I attempted this fix prior to asking my question; `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` didn't work, and the system clock was accurate even before I reconfigured it, so I don't think this is my issue.

Comment: Similar situation to me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424269/network-problems-after-upgrading-to-22-04-1

Answer (score 1):

```
    ifup[1634]: /etc/network/if-up.d/resolved: 12: mystatedir: not found
```

There are lines 11-13 in `/etc/network/if-up.d/resolved`, it looks like:

```
if systemctl is-enabled systemd-resolved > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    mystatedir statedir ifindex interface
```

And later in line 26:

```
    mystatedir=/run/network
```

This means: word with variable name `mystatedir` is used as executable file's name placed at a $PATH. This script has not been tested. Most probably smth. like `local` keyword missed at line start.

May be all the rest has not been verified too.

Comment: I have this on my local system as well, but is harmless because networking functions fine.  It appears to be a bug in the `ifupdown` , and my guess is it's unlikely to be fixed since those packages aren't being maintained in favor of netplan (ubuntu rule #1: if it ain't broke, let's "fix" it!)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes to this after upgrading to 22.04 on Digitalocean, or potentially other cloud providers, the following might help.

I was unable to access my droplet after upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04 on Digitalocean, and from the recovery console KVM, was able to see no networking available with the classic "Network is unreachable" from a direct IP ping.

`ip a` showed no ip address or gateway given.

Turns out, in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/50-cloud-init.cfg` there were a few new lines added:

```
# control-alias eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.17.0.6
    netmask 255.255.0.0
```

These overrode my eth0 interface configuration with the correct ip address and gateway, and caused the interface to have the incorrect configuration.

Removing them resolved the issue.