# Network problems after upgrading to 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish

Tags: networking, upgrade, 22.04

On my first hard reboot after upgrading my laptop to 22.04, I noticed problems accessing the internet using either wired or wifi connections.

Unlike other users ( [Broken network configuration after upgrade to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423937/broken-network-configuration-after-upgrade-to-22-04) and [Network Problems after upgrading to 22.04.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424269/network-problems-after-upgrading-to-22-04-1) ), my pings to localhost / 128.0.0.1 succeed 100%, as do pings to my router (192.168.1.1), and I am able to log in to my router from a browser to verify that everything seems fine on the router end. My phone is still able to access the internet via wifi.

Results of `ping -c 10 2001:4860:4860::8888`: (Ipv6 to google.com)

```
PING 2001:4860:4860::8888(2001:4860:4860::8888) 56 data bytes

--- 2001:4860:4860::8888 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9211ms
```

Results of ifconfig:

```
enx803f5d0e2b8f: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.23  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::d1f9:5e5d:2b3b:807d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 80:3f:5d:0e:2b:8f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 64  bytes 10712 (10.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 22  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 47  bytes 9636 (9.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ipv6leakintrf0: flags=195<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fdeb:446c:912d:8da::  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::47e9:ccfd:4704:eb42  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fa:7f:7d:d6:b3:7e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23  bytes 3578 (3.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 117  bytes 9577 (9.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 117  bytes 9577 (9.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.20  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::8f2a:29b2:2493:7888  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:28:f8:6c:82:39  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 18  bytes 4672 (4.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 35  bytes 6534 (6.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I tried disabling wired and using only wifi, and also tried disabling wifi and using only wired. Same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with ProtonVPN, which was behaving as though I had uninstalled it without disabling the kill switch. It didn't occur to me that the VPN might be at fault because the app hasn't been set up to start on startup on my machine, and when I tried to open the ProtonVPN app it gave me the infinite spinning wheel without the option to login or get to any settings (like the killswitch), so I assumed it was equally affected.

An irrelevant answer on this question [Ubuntu 22.04 Network doesn't work until NetworkManager restarted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425212/ubuntu-22-04-network-doesnt-work-until-networkmanager-restarted) gave me the suggestion that it might be Proton at fault.

Here is what ProtonVPN has to say about disabling the killswitch after uninstalling the app, at the bottom of [their linux installation help page](https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-ubuntu-vpn-setup/). This is what worked for me after my upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 (in which I didn't think I'd uninstalled ProtonVPN!). In my case it was pvpn-ipv6leak-protection.

> **2. How to disable the kill switch if you have uninstalled the app** You can easily turn off the kill switch inside our Linux app, but this
> isn’t possible if you have already uninstalled it. In this case, you
> can remove the kill switch and restore access to the internet as
> follows:
>
> a) Identify the Proton VPN connection name with the command:
>
> `nmcli connection show --active` This will show a list of your
> system’s active connections.
>
> b) Look for any connections that begin with prefix pvpn- This usually
> includes pvpn-killswitch and pvpn-ipv6leak-protection, and may include
> pvpn-routed-killswitch. Delete all these connections using the
> following command:
>
> `nmcli connection delete [connection name]`
>
> For example:
>
> `nmcli connection delete pvpn-killswitch`
>
> c) Re-run the following command to check that all Proton VPN
> connections have been removed:
>
> `nmcli connection show --active`
>
> If you see any Proton VPN connections left, delete them as described
> above.